# Does $0\prec B \prec A$ imply $A^{-1}B \prec I$

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

Does $0\prec B \prec A$ imply $A^{-1}B \prec I$?

I know:

1. $A,B$ are of the same size.
2. $A$, $B$ have strictly positive, real eigenvalues.
3. $A^{-1}B$ may not be symmetric since $A^{-1}$ and $B$ may not commute.
4. If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneous diagonalizable, this holds. This is because they have the same orthogonal eigenvectors. By diagonalization, we can prove this.

But even though $A^{-1}B$ is not symmetric, the definition for $M\prec N$ is that $$x^TMx < x^TNx, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Does this condition hold?

Comment: We do have $0 \prec A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} \prec I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given that $A, B, A-B$ are positive definite, and this also means $A^{-1}, B^{-1}$ are positive-definite. We want to show $I-A^{-1}B$ is positive definite. Note that:

$$I-A^{-1}B=A^{-1}(A-B)$$

Now, this is positive definite [if and only if its symmetric part is positive definite](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html), so we will instead look at its symmetric part:

$$\frac 1 2\left(A^{-1}(A-B)+(A-B)A^{-1}\right)$$

Now, [based off this forum post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366748/is-abba-positive-definite-too-if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite), if we choose the following, we will find that the above expression is actually not positive-definite:

$$A^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$A-B=\left[\begin{matrix}1/12 & 1/24 \\ 1/24 & 1/24\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now, from these equations, we find:

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1/6 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$B=\left[\begin{matrix}1/12 & -1/24 \\ -1/24   & 47/24\end{matrix}\right]$$

Here, $A, B, A-B$ are all positive definite, but:

$$A^{-1}B=\left[\begin{matrix} 1/2 & -1/4 \\ -1/48 & 47/48\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$I-A^{-1}B=\left[\begin{matrix}1/2 & 1/4 \\ 1/48 & 1/48\end{matrix}\right]$$

and according to Wolfram Alpha, this matrix $I-A^{-1}B$ is [not positive-definite](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+%7B%7B1%2F2,1%2F4%7D,%7B1%2F48,1%2F48%7D%7D+positive+definite). Thus, these choices of $A$ and $B$ are a counterexample to the theorem your question poses, so $0\prec B \prec A$ does not imply $A^{-1}B \prec I$.