# Sum of positive operators

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Assume $S_1, S_2: H \to H$ are bounded, positive and self-adjoint operators on a real Hilbert space $H$. Clearly,
$$\langle (S_1 + S_2)u, u \rangle = \langle S_1 u, u \rangle + \langle S_2 u , u\rangle \geq \langle S_1 u, u \rangle.$$
Is it true that
$$ \langle (S_1 + S_2)^m u, u \rangle \geq \langle S_1^m u, u \rangle, \quad m = 2, 3, \dots \, ?$$
For matrices that commute, this is true by diagonalization, but the general case is less clear to me. For $m = 2$ and general matrices, the statement is equivalent to $S_1 S_2 + S_2 S_1$ having only non-negative eigenvalue.

EDIT: I found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366748/is-abba-positive-definite-too-if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite), the accepted answer of which proves that the statement I wrote is not true in the general case.

Comment: So then the question is answered? You should explicitly post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is not true. Assume $S_1$ and $S_2$ are positive semi-definite matrices and consider $m = 2$. We will prove that there exist $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that the right-hand side of
$$(S_1 + S_2)^2 - S_1^2 = S_1 S_2 + S_2 S_2 + S_2^2$$
has a negative eigenvalue. Let $A$ and $B$ be as in the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366748/is-abba-positive-definite-too-if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite), and let $S_1 = A/s$, $S_2 = s B$ for some $s \in \mathbb R$. As $s \to 0$, the right-hand side above tends to $AB + BA$, which implies that the right-hand side has a negative eigenvalue for small enough $s$.